# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "olé"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, historia, interjecciones

Aunque el tema se ha tratado de pasadas en algunas preguntas relacionadas, creo que todavía no se había planteado esta pregunta por aquí.

- En [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13231/12637), [Rodrigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/13232/12637) afirmaba que procedía de *ulular*.
- En [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2506/12637), más centrada en el cántico deportivo, [se dice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2508/12637) que se cree que es de origen árabe, de cuyo origen han derivado otras como el *hello* inglés o el *olá* portugués. Sin embargo, en el Merriam-Webster se afirma que "hello" viene de *[hollo](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hollo)*, y la etimología de ésta es desconocida.

En la RAE vienen recogidas tanto "ole" como "olé", significando lo siguiente:

> **[olé](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QykVr2u)**
>
> Voz expr.
>
> 1. interj. U. para animar y aplaudir. U. t. c. s. m.

No se comenta nada pues acerca de su posible origen. En la [Wikipedia en español](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ol%C3%A9) simplemente se dice que viene del árabe, y en la [Wikipedia en inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ol%C3%A9,_Ol%C3%A9,_Ol%C3%A9) se aventuran a añadir que podría ser una corrupción de *Allah*. Sin embargo, veo más plausible que de aquí se derivara la interjección *¡hala!* Por tanto, **¿alguien sabe cuál podría ser el origen de esta expresión tan famosa?**

Más datos: en el mapa de diccionarios de la RAE aparece desde la versión de 1884, siendo al parecer la voz *ole* más antigua que *olé*. En Ngram las primeras apariciones son de mediados del siglo XIX (ejemplo: [Poesías Andaluzas, 1841](https://books.google.es/books?id=gyxPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA39&dq=%22ole%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi04Yq45aDPAhWCvxoKHQZaCv44FBDoAQghMAE#v=onepage&q=%22ole%22&f=false): "Arsa y ole..."). Aunque según el Corominas, como apunta Rafael, es de aparición algo más temprana.

Comment: El Coromines se reduce a decir: "**¡OLE!**, h. 1780. Probte. es lo mismo que la interjección americana hole, empleada para llamar, variante de hola y hala, todas ellas de creación expresiva". O sea, ni él lo tenía claro.

Comment: La verdad es que googlear _origen olé_ da para escribir un libro con la cantidad de hipótesis. Incluso [etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?ole.-) aventura unas cuantas, destacando la hipótesis griega.

Comment: @fedorqui en ese caso, la recompensa irá para quien mejor recopile las teorías más comunes y explique cuáles pueden ser las más plausibles.

Comment: Soy árabe, esa palabra se utiliza muchísimo pero muchísimo es más que puedas imaginar. Tiene que ver con la palabra Allah (Dios). Cuando algo nos gusta mucho, decimos directamente "Allah!" (Olé) se usa en poesía,canto popular, flamenco, incluso en nuestros rezos y súplicas y oraciones... Para nosotros es una palabra muy muy muy especial también es más espiritual. Al pronunciarla, sentimos una especie de energia espiritual y una gran fuerza dentro de nosotros. Abrazo y saludos.

Comment: Los árabes musulmanes del Ándalus tienen una costumbre muy habitual, pues se reúnen en lugares muy populares ,zonas más conocidas,para bailar y cantar poesías... Los espectadores de inmediato se ponen de pie gritando "Allah!" Una forma de admiración y gusto Por la fiesta. De ahí fue el origen de Olé Olé = Madre mía / Dios mío / fenomenal / fantástico... Todos significan lo mismo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El DRAE no recoge la etimología, por lo que toca remangarse y buscar en la red.

Existen muchas hipótesis sobre el origen de la palabra “¡olé!” y sitios como [Cooking Ideas](http://www.cookingideas.es/origen-ole-20130911.html) o [Etimologias de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?ole.-) dan fe de ello:

> - **hay quienes afirman que viene del griego, del verbo “ololizin”** (ὀλολύζειν), que es una palabra onomatopéyica y designa el grito ritual de júbilo de duelo.

Esta hipótesis se contrarresta en Etimologías de Chile con el comentario:

> Creo bastante poco probable que nuestro olé tenga algo que ver con el griego *ololyzein*, cuyo significado práctico es más bien lanzar gritos agudos y prolongados, sobre todo por parte de las mujeres, en determinados rituales y especialmente en duelos. Esos gritos que expresa *ololyzein* se acabaron relacionando más que nada con el dolor o lo lúgubre, o el espantar malas influencias. En griego la expresión equivalente a nuestro ¡olé! y ¡bravo!, es *kalós*!, que es un grito alegre de aliento y alabanza.
>
> El griego *ololyzein* puede tener la misma raíz indoeuropea *u-, que el latín *ulula* (lechuza), a partir de la que se formó el verbo *ululare*, que se dice de humanos y animales para la idea de aullar o lanzar gritos agudos y penetrantes o incluso agudos y largos silbidos, y que nos da nuestro verbo ulular, que tiene un significado lúgubre.

Sigamos con las opciones:

> - **hay quienes también dicen que “¡Olé!” viene del episodio de la Biblia** en el que Jacob es engañado el día de su boda con Raquel, al quitar el velo a la novia, descubre que en realidad se trata de Lea, no de Raquel. El público durante la ceremonia, intenta avisarle “¡Oh, Lea!”. Y de ahí derivó a olé.
>
> - Pero la hipótesis más extendida y la que más cuerpo tiene es aquella que dice que **“¡olé!” viene del árabe, de la expresión “allah”** (Oh, Dios), concretamente.

Esta última es la que parece tener más adeptos.

> Según la escritora estadounidense Elizabeth Gilbert, “¡olé!” viene de la exclamación de “¡Alá!” (Allah). Los moros solían hacer grandes celebraciones que incluían espectáculos de baile. Cuando un bailarín lograba maravillar al público con sus movimientos llenos de gracia y su arte de gran nivel, se creía que ese momento permitía a los testigos entrever el poder de Alá a través del bailarín. Por eso, cuando los bailarines embrujaban al público, este exclamaba “¡Alá!”.

aunque una vez más en Etimologías la rechazan:

> Corriente<sup>1</sup> considera imposible que **olé** viniera de Alá ( الله *Allâh* ) porque ésta se pronuncia con una doble -**ll**- velarizada que impide que la -**á** final se pronuncie -**é**, y porque no hay explicación entonces para la **o**- inicial. Prefiere considerarla "voz de origen expresivo, como **hala**, **hola**, etc.

En [El origen de las palabras OLE y OLÉ](http://www.academia.edu/3125958/El_origen_de_las_palabras_OLE_y_OL%C3%89) podemos ver un análisis pormenorizado del que intentaré ir añadiendo las partes más relevantes.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo gracias por otorgarme la recompensa, nunca había ganado ninguna : ) Sé que no es tan exhaustivo como debería, así que intentaré volver a la publicación para aportar más datos. Si alguien quiere, puede ayudarme; en tal caso, pasaré la respuesta a Community Wiki. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 4):

En el CVC (Centro Virtual Cervantes) hay un hilo sobre la etimología de OLÉ.
[Significado y origen de la palabra 'olé'](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=25251)

Resumiendo el contenido del enlace al foro del CVC:

> Hay opiniones sobre que puede venir del las aleyas del corán, comenzaban siempre "Alá ...". Aunque el etimólogo, Joan Corominas, tiene sus dudas.
>   Eso es lo que afirman todos los expertos en etimología. Wa-llâh es una exclamación árabe "¡Por Alá!" que aparece entre nosotros como "Olé". No es raro, teniendo en cuenta el sonido de la A de Allâh, que se aproxima al de nuestra O.
>   Y acabando con el arabista Emilio García Gómez para quién, efectivamente, nuestro «¡olé!» deriva de la tradicional exclamación musulmana que, sonando como Wa-llâh, significa '¡por Dios!'. Solo que desfigurada a propósito por los moriscos como 'Wallé' para evitar que pudiera parecer invocación religiosa lo que no era sino expresión maquinal de admiración.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que puede venir del celebérrimo Lazarillo de Tormes que tras jugársela al ciego le grita que bien olió la longaniza pero no olió el poste, y repite "ole, ole ahora", ignoro si hay uso de este término antes del 1500 pero si no yo apostaría por este origen.

Answer (score 0):

De la expresión admirativa de los espectadores en torneos y justas, cuando aparecía en el campo su campeón, el caballero favorito, su paladín:

```
         ¡HE LE! ¡HE LO! (= Hele ahí, helo ahí)
```