# ¿Hay palabras con más etimologías propuestas que "galimatías"?

Tags: etimología, rae, dle, curiosidades

Buscando en el [**NTLLE**](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUIMenuNtlle?cmd=Lema&sec=1.0.0.0.0.) la etimología de **galimatías**, he encontrado:

**Terreros y Pando 1787**

> *M. Huet* cree que esta voz quedó de un pleito, en que se disputaba de un *gallo* propio de un hombre llamado *Matias*, y en que los alegatos se ponian en latin; y como el Abogado se embrollase á fuerza de repetir *Gallus & Mathias*, en lugar de decir *Gallus Mathiae*, decía *Galli Mathias*, de donde quedó *Galimatias*.

**Zerolo 1895, RAE 1899, Pages 1914, Rodríguez Navas 1918**

> Del b. lat *ballimatia*, címbalo

**RAE 1956, RAE 1970, RAE 1984**

> Del fr. *galimatias*, invención jocosa del siglo XVI; de *galli*, gallo, y el gr. *μάθεία*, enseñanza.

**RAE 1992**

> Del fr. *galimatias*, discurso o escrito embrollado

[**RAE 2001**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/) y **RAE actual**

> Del fr. *galimatias*, discurso o escrito embrollado, y este del gr. *κατὰ Ματθαῖον*, según Mateo, por la manera en que este evangelista describe la genealogía que figura al comienzo de su Evangelio.

En **etimologías.dechile.net** se menciona, además:

> Otros sostienen que vendría del latín vulgar *ballimathia* que Isidoro de Sevilla (c. 565-636) glosaba: *inhonestae cantationes*, canciones obscenas.

En conjunto, parece que a lo largo de los siglos se han propuesto ¡media docena de etimologías diferentes!

Comment: ¿Qué tal "[olé](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18084/12637)?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo: A diferencia de "olé", en este caso, la propia Real Academia ha admitido 3 etimologías diferentes !!

Comment: Entiendo. Visto así, supongo que la RAE habrá ido refinando la etimología según los nuevos descubrimientos e investigaciones, y a día de hoy solo defenderán la última propuesta. En todo caso, la pregunta parece interesante, y la entiendo como la búsqueda de una palabra cuya etimología haya sido incierta para la RAE de modo que hayan tenido que irla variando con el tiempo.

Comment: Debe de haber muchas palabras que respondan a tu pregunta. Por ejemplo, en el primer diccionario de la RAE se decía que "ola" era una corrupción del latín _unda_. Luego pasó a provenir del bretón durante muchas ediciones, y solo recientemente pasó a ser "de origen incierto".

Answer (score 2):

#### [Bastardo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5BTZ46N)

Academia autoridades (1726):

> - El P. Guadix [...] dice que es voz Arábiga *Baxtaridû*, que vale lo mismo que de quien quisiéredes, por no saberse de cierto quienes
>     fueron los padres.
> - Otros deducen el origen del Latino *Burdus*, que es el macho hijo de yegua y de asno, y que de Bustardo se dixo Bastardo.

Academia usual (1884):

> - ¿Del fr. *bas*, bajo, y del célt. *tarz*, extracción?

Academia usual (1899 hasta 1947):

> - De *basto*.

Academia usual (1956 hasta 1992):

> - Del ant. fr. *bastard*.

Academia usual (2001 hasta la actualidad):

> - Del ant. fr. *bastart*.

Total: hasta 6 etimologías diferentes propuestas a lo largo del tiempo (aunque las dos últimas solo varíen en una letra), y únicamente por la RAE.

Otros diccionarios, como el Rosal de 1611:

> - Del gr. q. llamó Bassarída o Bastarída a la muger publica o Ramera.

Terreros y Pando (1786):

> - Bastardo es del Balc. *Baftarric du, hijo habido ocultamente*.

Y para rematar el festival, ya que la RAE dice que viene del francés, he aquí lo que dice [el Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/b%C3%A2tard/8313?q=b%C3%A2tard#8265):

> - Latin medieval *bastardus*, del germánico *banstu-*, segundo matrimonio con una mujer de menor rango.

Bonus: Corominas profundiza en la etimología actual del DLE:

> Tomado del fr. ant. *bastart* [...], quizá deriv. de *bast* 'albarda' por alusión a los hijos nacidos de las relaciones de arrieros con mozas de posada, como las de la Maritornes del Quijote.