# ¿Cuándo se comenzaron a escribir los signos de puntuación pegados a la palabra precedente?

Tags: ortografía, historia, puntuación

Buscando información sobre [palabras con muchas etimologías propuestas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18834/12637), encontré la definición de *bastardo* en el diccionario de autoridades de la RAE (1726) de la siguiente forma:

[image: Bastardo]

Lo que me llama la atención de este texto es que las comas (,) y los dos puntos (:) se escriben dejando un espacio entre estos y las palabras precedentes. En cambio, el punto (.) sí parece escribirse siempre pegado a la palabra anterior. ¿Era la regla por entonces escribir algunos signos de puntuación separados? Si es así, ¿qué signos debían escribirse con un espacio de por medio? ¿Cuándo se unificó esta norma para que los signos siempre se escribieran pegados a la palabra anterior?

Comment: Por ejemplo en el francés aún se mantiene el espacio antes de los dos puntos y las comillas angulares: [_« Jungle » de Calais : après l’évacuation, le sentiment de « vide » des associatifs et bénévoles_](http://www.lemonde.fr/societe/article/2016/11/22/jungle-de-calais-apres-l-evacuation-le-sentiment-de-vide-des-associatifs-et-benevoles_5035535_3224.html).

Comment: En este libro de gramática de 1859 [Gramatica de la Lengua Castellana](https://archive.org/details/gramaticadelale00lpgoog) deja espacios entre los dos puntos, punto y coma, signos de interrogación y exclamación; sin embargo en las comas a veces deja espacio y otras no. En el capítulo que habla de los signos de puntuación no dice nada sobre los espacios

Comment: @blonfu sí, en el diccionario de autoridades también pasa que a veces la coma se escribe también pegada a la palabra precedente, sobre todo si es a final de línea.

Comment: En este otro ya no hay espacios (1883): https://archive.org/details/gramticadelalen06espagoog ni en otros posteriores que he mirado. Tampoco dice nada en el capítulo sobre puntuación. ¿Estará el asunto entre 1859 y 1883?

Comment: @blonfu pues seguramente, porque los diccionarios de la RAE de 1869 y 1884 sufren un cambio parecido: pasan de tener los signos separados a pegados. Algo debió pasar en ese periodo.

Comment: En el [Prontuario de ortografía de la lengua castellana](http://www.bibliotecanacional.gov.co/recursos_user/digitalizados/fpineda_48_pza5.pdf) de 1850 (edición Colombia) no veo espacio antes de los dos puntos. Por cierto, hablan de _punto i coma_ (con _i_ latina). ¿Y si fue una moda afrancesada que cayó en desuso con la vuelta a la españa absolutista?

Comment: @fedorqui pues tampoco te extrañe, ya he leído en varios sitios que durante los primeros tiempos de la RAE, esta estuvo bastante influenciada por la academia francesa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es probable que la respuesta a esta pregunta no se encuentre en las reglas de puntuación sino en las cuestiones técnicas detrás de los textos mencionados. Recordemos que en esos tiempos la impresión de libros se realizaba de manera "manual", es decir, los tipos (las piezas metálicas para aplicar la tinta al papel) se unían uno a uno a mano en un soporte, es hasta 1885 que se inventa la [linotipia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linotipia).

Esto explica porque incluso "ra" en "otras" y "(pri-)mera" no es consistente: Su alineación vertical es diferente. De igual manera, explica porque a veces existe el espacio y otras no.

Es probable que en un futuro haya gente que se pregunte acerca de las diferencias entre los trabajos que se llevaron a cabo en máquinas de escribir contra aquellos resultados de las primeras máquinas impresoras, una vez que las computadoras personales comenzaron a proliferar.