# ¿Cuál es la palabra del español con más etimologías diferentes admitidas por la RAE?

Tags: etimología, solicitud-de-término, rae, dle, curiosidades

Ahí va una nueva pregunta de curiosidad. Cuando una palabra del español tiene diversos significados, si estos provienen de etimologías diferentes se agrupan en artículos independientes del diccionario, usando para ello los superíndices. A estas voces de distinta etimología que coinciden en la forma se les llama *homógrafos*. Así, hoy he encontrado la palabra *cacho*, que tiene [cuatro homógrafos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6Xvqvzr|6XyvW01|6Y1ViAh|6Y5PBu3):

- *cacho<sup>1</sup>* (del latín vulgar *caccŭlus*),
- *cacho<sup>2</sup>* (del latín vulgar *cattŭlus*),
- *cacho<sup>3</sup>* (de origen incierto) y
- *cacho<sup>4</sup>* (del latín *coactus*).

¿Cuál es la palabra del español que tiene más homógrafos (etimologías diferentes reconocidas por la RAE)?

Comment: No confundir con [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18834/12637) en la que se pedía la palabra cuya etimología ha sufrido más propuestas y cambios a lo largo de su historia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buscando en el DIRAE siguiendo el [truquillo de Charlie](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40270158#40270158) he detectado que el número máximo de etimologías diferentes en el DLE es seis.

Además de ***coca*** que propone [Charlie en su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22539/1674), hay tres más: ***bote***, ***coto*** y ***radio*** (búsqueda de [`site:dirae.es "etimología 6"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adirae.es%20%22etimolog%C3%ADa%206%22) en Google).

[**radio**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=V1GlXnv%7CV1HlZk4%7CV1HspiD%7CV1J0Z3h%7CV1LdofK%7CV1M4aB1), cuatro de ellos son acortamientos

- radio<sup>1</sup> (Del lat. radius)
- radio<sup>2</sup> (Del fr. radium, y este de radioactif 'radioactivo' e -ium '-io'.)
- radio<sup>3</sup> (Acort. de radiodifusión)
- radio<sup>4</sup> (Acort. coloq. de radiorreceptor)
- radio<sup>5</sup> (Acort. de radiotelegrama)
- radio<sup>6</sup> (Acort. de radiotelegrafista)

*Acort. = Acortamiento*

[**bote**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5yatllK%7C5yboas9%7C5yc2i2E%7C5ycMwec%7C5ycy6L2%7C5yg7rxF)

- bote<sup>1</sup> (De botar)
- bote<sup>2</sup> (Cf. pote.)
- bote<sup>3</sup> (Del ingl. ant. bāt.)
- bote<sup>4</sup> (Del germ. *bukko; cf. a. al. medio boc, a. al. ant. bukk, al. Bock.)
- bote<sup>5</sup> (para expresiones *de bote a bote* que en Argentina quiere decir *de bote en bote*) y *de bote en bote* (Dicho de un sitio o de un local: Lleno de gente completamente)
- bote<sup>6</sup> (en Cuba Hoja pequeña de tabaco, después del primer corte, usada para la picadura)

[**coto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B9OoKiA%7CB9S8DA6%7CB9UHblX%7CB9XoglB%7CB9XqFet%7CB9ZsgbA)

- coto<sup>1</sup> (Del lat. cautus 'defendido')
- coto<sup>2</sup> (Del lat. quotus 'cuánto')
- coto<sup>3</sup> (Del lat. cubĭtus)
- coto<sup>4</sup> (Del lat. cient. cottus, y este del gr. κόττος kóttos)
- coto<sup>5</sup> (Del quechua koto 'papera' → 1. m. Arg., Bol., Chile, Col., Ec., Par. y Perú. bocio)
- coto<sup>6</sup>, ta (Cf. cuto. → 1. adj. Nic. Dicho de una persona: Privada de un brazo)

*Cf = [Confer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confer)* → quiere decir *véase*

Comment: Cuando [le pregunté a la RAE](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/913720119112667136) si había alguna palabra con más de seis homógrafos, [me respondieron](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/913743654216400896) con su habitual "disculpe, pero este servicio solo atiende dudas sobre el uso normativo del español".

Comment: @Charlie jejeje siempre explorando los límites del _off topic_ :P

Comment: No, no, siempre explorando nuevos horizontes, que queda mejor. :-D

Answer (score 4):

Trasteando un poco con el DIRAE acabo de encontrar una de 6: ***[coca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9Y3W1Jj|9Y7V25X|9Y9qSyT|9YA1APW|9YAFDMl|9YCpRLr)***. Sus etimologías son:

- coca<sup>1</sup> (del quechua y aimara *kuka*),
- coca<sup>2</sup> (del latín *coccus*),
- coca<sup>3</sup> (de *coco*),
- coca<sup>4</sup> (del latín *concha*),
- coca<sup>5</sup> (del catalán *coca*), y
- coca<sup>6</sup> (acortamiento de *cocaína*).

Comment: ¡Interesante!. Me parece además curioso porque separan las definiciones 1 y 6. Del quechua kuka sale la palabra coca (1) de la cual deriva cocaína que luego se acorta y la reintroducen como la 6. Para mi (1)=(6). Son la misma cosa/coca.

Comment: @DGaleano pero coca1 es el arbusto y coca6 es la droga. No son lo mismo, ¿no?

Comment: Puede ser, pero respecto al arbusto siempre nos referimos a él como _la mata de coca_ o hablamos de _la hoja de coca_ etc. Igual, ya es hilar muy fino. Son curiosidades del lenguaje y de quienes lo usamos de infinitas maneras. BTW me confundiste con ese cambio de nombre. Casi te doy la bienvenida jajajaja.

Comment: @DGaleano juas, siento la confusión, pero se me empezaba a hacer raro usar mi nombre formal en un sitio en el que me siento entre amigos, así que lo cambié por el apodo por el que me conocen mis colegas.

Answer (score -1):

**ser**

1. copulat. U. para afirmar del sujeto lo que significa el atributo.
2. aux. U. para conjugar todos los verbos en la voz pasiva.
3. intr. Haber o existir.
4. intr. Indica tiempo. Son las tres.
5. intr. ser capaz o servir. Los idiomas son PARA comunicarse.
6. intr. Estar en lugar o situación.
7. intr. Suceder, acontecer, tener lugar. ¿Dónde fue la boda? El partido fue a las seis.
8. intr. Valer, costar. ¿A cómo es la merluza?
9. intr. Indica relación de posesión. Este jardín es DE la reina.
10. intr. Opinar del mismo modo que alguien. Soy CON Ana.
11. intr. Seguir el partido o la opinión de alguien. Soy DE Juan.
12. intr. Mantener la amistad de alguien. Es DE sus amigos. Es muy DE sus antiguos compañeros.
13. intr. Corresponder, parecer propio. Este proceder no es de un hombre de bien.
14. intr. Formar parte de una corporación o comunidad. Es del Consejo. Es de la Academia.
15. intr. Tener principio, origen o naturaleza, hablando de los lugares o países. Antonio es de Madrid.
16. intr. U. para afirmar o negar en lo que se dice o pretende. Esto es.

Comment: Pero claro. Tenía que ser *ser*

Comment: @DGaleano   Así ES...  ;)

Comment: Nótese que no he pedido la palabra con más acepciones, para eso tenemos otra pregunta (spoiler: es "pasar" con más de 50). He pedido la palabra con más homógrafos (etimologías diferentes). Has puesto las acepciones del verbo "ser", que provienen todas de una misma etimología. Cc: @DGaleano