# ¿Por qué dice la RAE que "beicon" viene del latín medieval?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos

Me resulta curiosa la entrada en el DLE de la palabra *bacón*:

> **[bacón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4kwa25N)**
>
> Del lat. mediev. *baco, -onis*; en acep. 1, del ingl. *bacon*.
>
> 1. m. **beicon**.
> 2. m. desus. Pieza de tocino de cerdo.

Por un lado, pensaba que las diferentes acepciones de una palabra generaban entradas diferentes en el DLE (es decir, debería existir una entrada *bacon<sup>1</sup>* y *bacon<sup>2</sup>*). Por otro lado, la acepción que es sinónima de *beicon* se muestra como proveniente del inglés, y cuando consultamos *beicon* en el DLE encontramos lo siguiente:

> **[beicon](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5IMmcG1)**
>
> Del ingl. *bacon*, y este del lat. mediev. *baco, -onis*.
>
> 1. m. Panceta ahumada.

Es decir, el DLE insiste en su origen latino a pesar de provenir del inglés, por lo que podría parecer que esta es otra de las palabras que buscaba la pregunta sobre [etimologías cíclicas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22988/12637).

Sin embargo, buscando la etimología de *beicon* encontramos:

- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bacon): "Middle English, from Anglo-French, of Germanic origin; akin to Old High German *bahho* side of bacon, *bah* back." Es decir, dice que la palabra es pariente de *back* ("espalda"), y que su origen es germánico.
- [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bacon): "From Old French *bacon*, from Proto-Germanic **bakkon* 'back meat'." Dice que la palabra proviene del francés antiguo, que al parecer se hablaba en el norte de Francia, y propone una etimología pues relacionada con el germánico más que con el latín.

He buscado otros diccionarios con resultados similares, el único que he encontrado que dice que podría provenir del latín es el [etymologiebank.nl](http://etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/bacon1) (la traducción automática -pero corregida- de la página dice "derivado del *bacon* inglés, antiguo *Bakoun* [ca. 1330; BDE] < francés antiguo *bacon, bacoun* o latín medieval *baconem* (acusativo de *bac(c)o*) 'tocino'"). Es decir, la proveniencia del latín medieval es una opción alternativa a la del francés antiguo (y por ende del germánico).

Sin embargo, la RAE parece tenerlo muy claro. Si en la edición del DLE de 1992 solo decían que venía del inglés *bacon*, ¿por qué ahora la RAE lo afirma sin dudar? ¿Qué estudios categóricos existen acerca del origen de esta palabra? ¿Qué saben ellos que nosotros no sepamos?

Comment: Respecto lo de _las diferentes acepciones de una palabra generaban entradas diferentes en el DLE (es decir, debería existir una entrada bacon1 y bacon2)_, también a mí me surge la duda de cuál es el criterio. ¿No iba por [etimologías diferentes de la palabra](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22538/1674)?

Comment: @fedorqui eso pensaba yo, pero ahora que lo pienso si el DLE dice que _beicon_ viene de _baco, -onis_, al final las dos acepciones vendrían del mismo sitio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según el *Etymological Dictionary of Proto-Germanic* de Guus Kroonen (Leiden, 2013) ([PDF](http://www.bulgari-istoria-2010.com/Rechnici/A_Lyubotski_Proto_Germanik_dict.pdf)) la palabra inglesa *bacon* deriva del protogermánico **bakan-*, de la raíz **baka-* "espalda"; "bacon, tocino" aparece como *bahho* en alto alemán antiguo. (La palabra alemana moderna para el tocino es *Speck*.) Esta raíz fue tomada prestada por el eslavo y su significado pasó de "espalda" a "flanco" (el tocino puede provenir precisamente de la espalda o de los flancos del cerdo).

[image: *baka-]

Por otro lado, en el Wikcionario dice que el latín medieval **ba(c)cō* (gen. **bacōnis*) es un préstamo del fráncico **bakō* "jamón, costado de un animal". El fráncico es una lengua germánica de la rama occidental hablado entre los siglos IV y VIII d. C. que aportó muchos préstamos al francés antiguo e influyó en general a las lenguas romances habladas en la Galia en ese período.

En resumen: la palabra es de origen germánico (con una raíz muy antigua). El latín medieval la tomó del fráncico y la pasó al francés antiguo, de donde pudo pasar al inglés quizá durante el período de dominio normando.

La diferenciación en dos acepciones que hace el DLE parece deberse a que la misma palabra puede haber entrado al castellano directamente desde el latín medieval, por un lado, y desde el inglés, más recientemente, por el otro. En el CORDE hay una sola aparición de *bacon* [en un texto del siglo XIV](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=111117%5C000%5CC003O11112017000328077.1172.1168&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20bacon%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0), y luego nada [hasta el s. XVII](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=2&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=111117%5C000%5CC003O11112017000328077.1172.1168&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20bacon%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto2), y después apenas un puñado más hasta el s. XX. ¿Tendrá esto que ver con estas dos acepciones?