# ¿Tiene algo que ver "cacho" con "zurdo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, españa

Leyendo *Zalacaín el aventurero* de Pío Baroja me encuentro con esta frase:

> Tenía Martín un rival en un chico navarro, de la Ribera del Ebro, hijo de un carabinero. A este rival **le llamaban el *Cacho*, porque era zurdo**.

La verdad es que la asociación de ideas cacho -> zurdo se me hace extraña. Históricamente el zurdo era mal visto (¡incluso a mí de pequeño mi abuelo me decía que me cambiara a diestro!) y de ahi pienso que podría pensarse *cacho* como sinónimo de algo malo.

Pero resulta que *cacho* es una palabra con múltiples acepciones (como se vio en [¿Cuál es la palabra del español con más etimologías diferentes admitidas por la RAE?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22538/1674)) y, de ellas, me quedaría tal vez con la 4.ª:

> [**cacho<sup>4</sup>, cha**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6Xvqvzr%7C6XyvW01%7C6Y1ViAh%7C6Y5PBu3)
>   `Del lat. coactus, part. pas. de cogĕre 'recoger', 'reunir, congregar'.`
>
> 1. adj. [**gacho**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=IgsL1Is).
>
> > `Relacionado con agachar.`
> >
> > 1. adj. Encorvado, inclinado hacia la tierra.
> > 2. adj. Dicho de un buey o de una vaca: Que tiene uno de los cuernos o ambos inclinados hacia abajo.
> > 3. adj. Dicho de un caballo o de una yegua: Muy enfrenado, que tiene el hocico muy metido al pecho, a distinción de los despapados, que levantan mucho la cabeza.
> > 4. adj. Dicho de un cuerno: Torcido hacia abajo.

Para el cual yo relacionaría (libremente) *gacho* con el "gauche" francés que quiere decir *izquierda*. Pero no sé si la cosa va por allí o tiene una explicación más simple.

Entonces, ¿por qué se relaciona *cacho* con zurdo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La voz *cacho* se relaciona con *zurdo* porque significa exactamente eso. En el *Vocabulario navarro* de Iribarren y Ollaquindia se lee:

> **CACHO, CHA.** Zurdo. (En Aragón, *cucho*). *Cacha* llaman a la mano izquierda. [Ribera, Aóiz].

Recordemos que Pío Baroja nació en San Sebastián, luego el uso de *cacho* como "zurdo" no le debía de ser desconocido. Desconocida sí resulta en cambio esa acepción para el resto del mundo, dado que no consigo encontrarla en ningún diccionario de los consultados a través del NTLLE. Afortunadamente queda la ficha recogida en el *Fichero general* de la RAE, de donde extraje la información.

Comment: Oh, pensé que era únicamente _ezkerra_.

Comment: ¿Y de donde viene *cacho*?¿Del euskera?

Comment: @blonfu de los cuatro orígenes diferentes que tiene la voz, tres provienen del latín y uno (el de _cacho_ como "cuerno") es de origen incierto.

Comment: me referia al caso concreto de cacho como sinónimo de zurdo

Comment: @blonfu ah, perdón, pues no lo sé, ese uso solo lo he visto en el citado _Vocabulario navarro_ y no indicaba etimología. Creo que hace referencia a _cacho_ como "gacho", que según el NTLLE también se usaba para cosas como "torcido" o "flojo", y de ahí pudo derivar su uso como "zurdo". En ese caso vendría del latín _coactus_, según el DLE.

Comment: Sí de hecho lo de sinónimo de _gacho_ lo recogía en la pregunta, lo que me hizo elaborar la hipótesis de que algo zurdo es algo malo. Entonces, @blonfu, ¿_cacho_ no significa nada en vasco?

Comment: @fedorqui pues nunca lo había oído pero buscando a raiz de esta pregunta parece que sí y que tiene varias acepciones, una de ellas, efectivamente, es zurdo: https://www.euskaltzaindia.eus/index.php?option=com_oehberria&task=bilaketa&Itemid=413&lang=eu&definizioak=0&query=katxo&sarrera=170806

Comment: Pues duda resuelta, ¡muchas gracias @blonfu y Charlie!