# Where does the word "quicio" come from?

Tags: vocabulario, etimología

The ***quicio*** of a door is basically the part where it joins the frame:

> [**quicio**](http://dle.rae.es/?w=quicio)
>
> 1. m. Parte de las puertas o ventanas en que entra el espigón del quicial, y en que se mueve y gira.

It is used figuratively in expressions like "sacar de quicio", meaning "to exasperate, to take on somebody's nerves".

But the DLE entry does not include the origin of the word ("from Lat. *quicium*" or something like that), so...

**What is the origin / etymology of *quicio*?**

Comment: Tema complicado. Corominas, en el Diccionario etimológico, le dedica 8 columnas de 60 líneas. El origen es incierto, una teoría que da la hace derivar de un verbo latino no atestiguado _\*excrepitare_, de ahí "desquiciar" y de ésta "quicio". Como el diccionario es de 1984 y quizás hoy  haya nuevos datos, no lo pongo como respuesta.

Comment: @angus Ha falta de otra explicación estaría bien que pusieras esa teoría en modo de respuesta y con más datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues parece que nos va a pasar lo mismo que con *[bastardo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18849/12637)*, que ha tenido diversas etimologías propuestas conforme ha ido pasando el tiempo, si se le han dedicado tantas líneas.

En todo caso, y por proponer las etimologías más antiguas que se conocen, el diccionario de Rosal de 1611 propone la siguiente:

> Quicio, del hebreo que se llama *Hisçuq*, y al lugar sobre el que alguna cosa se mueve. *Kisçór*, que es lo mesmo que Quicio.

Así pues, en su etimología más antigua se propone que viene del hebreo. Aunque igualmente antigua es la etimología de Covarrubias, citada por el *Diccionario de Autoridades*:

> Covarrubias quiere salga de la voz Latina *Quiescere*, porque moviendose la puerta o ventana, él se está quieto.

El *Diccionario de Autoridades* opina pues que la etimología propuesta por Covarrubias es más un deseo que algo probado. No parece algo descabellado, ya que *quiescere* significa *descansar*, siendo a fin de cuentas el *quicio* el sitio donde descansa la puerta.

Aparte de estos posibles orígenes, muy pocas ediciones del DLE se aventuran a dar un origen de la palabra. Una que lo hace es la edición de 1884, en la que se lee:

> ¿Del bajo latín *acuties*, punta, clavo?

Nótese como el propio diccionario pone la etimología en entredicho. Y otros diccionarios aparte de los de la RAE tampoco aventuran posibles orígenes. Así que lo que ves en lo que podemos deducir partiendo del NTLLE. Me he puesto a consultar las cédulas del Fichero General, pero hay casi 500 y de momento solo encuentro referencias a la palabra en textos, nada sobre su origen.

Comment: Aquí hay una etimología interesante también: http://hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Sacar%20a%20alguien%20de%20quicio.htm. Creo que es la que apuntaba @angus en su comentario.

Comment: @blonfu con ese artículo te sale una respuesta muy maja. :-)