# ¿De dónde viene la palabra "soez"?

Tags: etimología, historia

[**Soez**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YDWmJ3u) aparece definido en el DLE como:

> De or. inc.
>   1. adj. Bajo, grosero, indigno, vil.

De toda la vida he tenido la idea de que procedía de la unión de **so** y **hez**, con pérdida de la ***h*** a lo largo del tiempo.

Sin embargo, al ver que el DLE indica un *orígen incierto* me ha entrado curiosidad.

Y mientras que **soez** y **soeces** aparecen en el CORDE cientos de veces, desde 1440 y 1541, respectivamente, tan solo hay un caso de **sohez** y ninguno de **so hez**.

¿De dónde viene, pues, *soez*?

Comment: El diccionario de la RAE en su edición de 1884 afirmaba sin lugar a dudas que, como dices, proviene de _so_, bajo, y _hez_.

Comment: @Charlie: Y poco después, en 1899, **del lat _subex_**, y en 1914: **quizá del mismo origen que _sucio_**

Comment: Perdón, no quería decir que el DLE de 1884 tuviera razón, solo que me resulta curioso que entonces lo afirmaran sin atisbo de duda. En otras preguntas ya [hemos descubierto](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18849/12637) que en muchas palabras la RAE ha ido variando su etimología a lo largo de las ediciones.

Answer (score 4):

La web [etimologías de chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?soez) también admite la etimología incierta, pero añade un par de posibilidades extras.

Aparte de la que incluyes en la pregunta (so- del latín "bajo" y hez- desecho), incluye una referencia a "An Etymological Dictionary of the Romance Languages; Chiefly from the German" de Friedrich Diez, que dice que

> vendría del latín *sus* (puerco).

(teoría a la que también hace referencia [esta web](https://definicion.de/soez/))

La tercera referencia sería a Corominas, que diría que el origen es la palabra tardía *sohez*, que vendría de *rahez* y este del árabe hispano *rahis* (que significa "barato").

Para ampliar un poco sobre esta última podemos consultar el [wiktionario](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/soez)

> Del castellano antiguo sohez, y este de origen incierto. Coromines sugiere que puede tratarse de una alteración de rehez, "vulgar", del árabe رَخِيص (raẖyṣ), "barato", reinterpretada como compuesto de re- y hez y modificada en su prefijo. Compárese el caso de zopenco

Answer (score 1):

Curiosamente, la etimología de Corominas en esta ocasión me parece poco creíble, pero la reproduzco aquí tal y como aparece en su *Breve diccionario etimológico*:

> **SOEZ** 'de baja estofa', 'vil, grosero', 1437. Teniendo en cuenta qe la grafía antigua es *sohez* y que es palabra tardía, quizá sea una modificación del antiguo sinónimo *rehez* (variante de *rahez*, SS. XIII-XV; procedente del ár. raḫîṣ 'barato'). Interpretado éste popularmente como un intensivo de la *hez* 'lo más vil, la inmundicia', se formaría *sohez* para expresar un mayor grado de abyección. Anticuado ya en el S. XVI, como propio del estilo de los libros de caballerías, *soez* volvió a entrar en circulación gracias al *Quijote*, en calidad de palabra literaria, que algunos, sólo desde el siglo pasado, han empleado incorectamente con el sentido de 'sucio' u 'obsceno'.

Efectivamente, si buscamos en el diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611, este nos confirma que ya entonces era palabra antigua:

> SOHEZ, palabra antigua, vale baxo, infame de poco valor, y la hez de la Republica, y assi se dixo de sub, y faex faecis.

Muy esclarecedoras las [acepciones de *faex, faecis*](http://latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/fax) en el diccionario, por cierto (*dregs* = "la parte más inútil de algo").

Para el caso propuesto por Corominas, no estoy seguro de que *rahez* sea un sinónimo de *sohez*. El *Diccionario de autoridades* lo define como "baxo, humilde y abatido", e indica que es voz anticuada. Curioso que exista un verso que relacione ambos términos, en todo caso:

> *No digo que te rahéces,
>
>   por tal via,
>
>   que sean en compañia
>
>   de sohéces.*

Se confunde a veces este uso de *rahez* o *rehez* con *raez*, que significaba "cosa fácil de hacer". Valga este ejemplo:

> *E otra vez vos digo: mas rehez cosa es el gamello pasar por el agujero de vna aguja: que el rico entrar enel rreyno delos cielos.* (a1485)

Aunque otras veces sí se usaba como peyorativo:

> *Atales avié d'ellos qe metién apellidos,
>
>   qe los oviera marras en Cogolla vencidos;
>
>   si de tan rehez omne fincassen escarnidos,
>
>   mucho máes lis valiera qe non fuessen nacidos.* (c1230)

Entiendo pues existe la posibilidad de que *sohez* sea un derivado de *rahez/rehez*. Aunque curiosamente también existe la posibilidad de que venga de *sub* como dice Covarrubias, dado que en diccionarios antiguos también existe la voz *suez*, más cercana a ese *sub* inicial, como en el diccionario español-inglés de Percival de 1591:

> **Suez**, base, filthie, naughtie, *Sordidus, foedus, malus.*

Vamos, que lo traduce al inglés como "bajo" y "sucio". Y en 1499 se usaba así:

> *Reuileo. les. lui. De re. que significa otra vez. et vileo. les. tornarse a enuilecer o a ser suez.*

Y hacia 1470 así, de nuevo relacionado con *raez*:

> *Desecha las pompas que nascen del brio
>
>   procura vianda de precio raez
>
>   cubre tu cuerpo con paño suez
>
>   que solo defienda las carnes del frio [...].*

Aquí *raez* se usa como "bajo" (de precio) y *suez* como "bajo" (de calidad).

Entiendo pues que ambas etimologías son posibles, y que incluso la expicación final pueda ser una mezcla de ambas.